# Terraform - Loop with for k,v on list inside map

Tags: terraform

I have a local value I want to split up and it looks like this:

```
old_local = {
  "ReaderAVD" = [
    "Reader",
    "DesktopVirtualizationUser",
    "VirtualMachineUserLogin"
    ]       
  "OwnerAVD" = [
    "Owner",
    "TagContributor",
    "DesktopVirtualizationUser",
    "VirtualMachineUserLogin"
    ]}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
new_local = [
    {
        "parent" = "ReaderAVD"
        "child"  = ["Reader"]
    },
    {
        "parent" = "ReaderAVD"
        "child"  = ["DesktopVirtualizationUser"]
    },
    {
        "parent" = "ReaderAVD"
        "child"  = ["VirtualMachineUserLogin"]
    },
    {
        "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
        "child"  = ["Owner"]
    },
    {
        "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
        "child"  = ["TagContributor"]
    },
    {
        "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
        "child"  = ["DesktopVirtualizationUser"]
    },
    {
        "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
        "child"  = ["VirtualMachineUserLogin"]
    }
]
```

I understand the principal of running for k,v loops inside each other but I don't know how to access the list or stop it creating all possible combinations. Here's what I have so far:

```
  nest_group = flatten([
    for index, item in local.tsg_nested_roles_list : [
      for key, value in local.tsg_nested_roles_list : {
        parent         = index
        child          = value
  }]])
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be easy to achieve by using the [`flatten` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten):

```
locals {
  new_local = flatten([
    for k, v in local.old_local : [
      for i in v : {
        parent = "${k}"
        child  = ["${i}"]
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Will yield:

```
[
    {
      "child" = ["Owner",]
      "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
    },
    {
      "child" = ["TagContributor",]
      "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
    },
    {
      "child" = ["DesktopVirtualizationUser",]
      "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
    },
    {
      "child" = ["VirtualMachineUserLogin",]
      "parent" = "OwnerAVD"
    },
    {
      "child" = ["Reader",]
      "parent" = "ReaderAVD"
    },
    {
      "child" = ["DesktopVirtualizationUser",]
      "parent" = "ReaderAVD"
    },
    {
      "child" = ["VirtualMachineUserLogin",]
      "parent" = "ReaderAVD"
    },
  ]
```